# Conflicting jetified-kotlin-reflect dependency

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

When I build my Android project, I get the following message:

```
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /home/janek/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.10/4d147bf43060dc43d61b096e24da1e67dfe0c032/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.10.jar (version 1.3)
    /home/janek/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/kotlin-reflect-1.0.6.jar/beba9d201a205f30041b70982540014d/jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.0.6.jar (version 1.0)
    /home/janek/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.11/4cbc5922a54376018307a731162ccaf3ef851a39/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.11.jar (version 1.3)
    /home/janek/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.11/d8b8e746e279f1c4f5e08bc14a96b82e6bb1de02/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.11.jar (version 1.3)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
```

But I have no idea why jetified-kotlin-reflect is even in there, since It isn't a dependency and does not even appear in `androidDependencies`.

Do you know where it comes from or how I can resolve this error?

Comment: This looks like a warning. Can you show us your `build.gradle` files?

Comment: I have about 15 build.gradle files, are you sure that would help? None of these have any reference to kotlin-reflect, and all kotlin libraries are version 1.3.

Answer (score 19):

I guess the kotlin plugin will automatically add the *kotlin-relfection.jar* if you use [reflection features](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) like *class literal syntax*.

> On the Java platform, the runtime component required for using the reflection features is distributed as a separate JAR file (kotlin-reflect.jar). This is done to reduce the required size of the runtime library for applications that do not use reflection features. If you do use reflection, please make sure that the .jar file is added to the classpath of your project.

I fixed the warnings by explicitly adding

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
```

to my build.gradle.

Comment: I had the same issue now with gradle 7 and kotlin 1.5.31, same package (reflect 1.4.31) older than the other ones, despite reflect not beind implemented explicitly. Solved with this, but it seems to be a bug in the plugin maybe?