# Duplicate class error when adding dependencies on MVVM Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am following a tutorial about jetpack compose and, the next step of the tutorial was to add this library. The library isn't being used yet. So, the app builds fine when it isn't included. But, adding this causes the duplicate class error. It doesn't however cause any issues while building the Gradle. From what I have researched so far, it seems that the issue is that this library contains some other library that has already been added separately and, I cannot identify the library. Also, I tried changing library versions for this to match other lifecycle libraries(older versions). I'll just drop below the Gradle file and the file that stores all the implementations.

## Error

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

## Here is my build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.3.1'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.43.2' apply false
}
```

## Here is my build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.jetpackcompose01'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jetpackcompose01"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    // Retrofit2
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    // Coil
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0")

    // ViewModel
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1'

    // Dagger Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44.2"


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
}
```

Comment: Try changing the version of kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion to '1.4.4'. If it doesn't help maybe this will, once you identify the library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662357/duplicate-class-kotlin-classes-kotlin-version-1-3-70?rq=2

Comment: It would be nice if you post the link to the tutorial :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion to match kotlin version helped and resolved the issue. In this case particularly, changing the kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion to '1.4.4' from '1.3.1' in order to match kotlin '1.8.10' was the correct fix.

Comment: How man can get know what ver of one lib matches another lib's version?

Comment: @Antares, here you are: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

Comment: thank you, but if we have e.g. 20 lib it is extremely hard to track all version dependencies. Changing ver of one cause incompatibility with another, and if you changes another one's version, it cause next and next problems... I am wondering if there is a good method except of resolving it step by step...

Comment: I don't know of any, unfortunately.